# Make a data-attribute behave like an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Is there a feasible way to make a data-attribute behave like an anchor?

Consider the possible situation below:

`<a id="link" href="#home">`

`<div data-section="home">`

Is it possible to somehow have the anchor tag tied to that div with the same named data-attribute?

This doesn't work but something kind of like:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
    var clickedLetter = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr("href", "#section[data-group='" + clickedLetter + "']")
});
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't use an `id` on that `div` instead?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it's dynamically generated markup coming from a database that I can't feasibly change at this point and was curious if something like this could be hacked together.

Comment: I don't quite understand your example code. Do you want the <div> to jump to the section marked in `data-section` just as an anchor tag would do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kawnah, in my opinion you need to get the href of clicked element

```
var clicked = $(this).attr('href');
```

After that, you can use replace function and get href without hashtag symbol (#)

```
var myAttr = replace('#', clicked);
```

And the last one you sholud to do is animate body to element had this data section

```
var elementScrolledTo = $('*[data-section="' + myAttr + '"]');

$('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: elementScrolledTo.offset().top
            }, 2000);
```

Of course, this is a handler function of jquery on event.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: overall great answer! I had to change it slightly - doing `var myAttr = replace('#', clicked);` was returning `##home` and causing and returning undefined in the animate so I needed to do `var myAttr = replace('#', ' ');` and now it's working great.